# I know vs I knows

Tags: word-usage

There is a sentence which confuses me often. Some say

1. I know the answer
2. I knows the answer

Which one of the above is correct? Explain in brief.

---

Also another sentence

> What proportion of people who were raised vegetarian eventually abandon(s) vegetarianism?

In the above sentence, is the usage of abandons correct? Please explain.

Comment: Did you look up [the conjugation for the verb *to know*](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-know.html)?  What conjugation do you think goes with *I*?

Comment: @stangdon  Thanks for the comment. Not that I didn't know the answer. I **know** the answer. I have seen it in a movie.Thought it's wrong. But I heard it in some one's conversation. Asked the question just to clarify.

Comment: There are some dialect forms of English in which the same verb conjugation is used with all personal pronouns - I knows, you knows, he knows, we knows, etc. - so that could potentially be what you heard.

Comment: People speak poorly/jokingly all the time. I knows is simply either of those.

Answer (score 2):

> I know the answer.

This is correct.  Use of "I know**s**" would be by a very young child or someone who was either untaught, or was taught English badly. The form **knows** is only used in third person singular: *He knows the answer.*

> What proportion ... abandon**s** vegetarianism?

Since the subject of the sentence is third person singular ("proportion" is an "it"), then **abandons** is correct. A plural subject would be different: *People sometimes abandon vegetarianism, but return to it later in their lives.*

Answer (score 1):

"I know" is correct.

English, like many languages, as different forms of the verb depending on the person and number of the noun. English, unlike many languages, has just two forms for most verbs: with an "s" at the end for third person singular, no "s" for every other case.

I know, you know, he/she/it knows
we know, you know, they know

There are some exceptions:

I have, you have, he/she/it has
we have, you have, they have

"To be" has three forms: am, are, and is:

I am, you are, he/she/it is
we are, you are, they are

There are a handful of other verbs that do not follow the normal pattern. But in general, add an "s" to the end for third person singular.